# Struggling to convert timezones GMT to CST in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, pytz

I've spent hours on this, but my brain can't seem to figure it out, and it seems a lot of info I've found applies to Python 2?

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import pytz
time_stamp = 'Mon, 17 Dec 2018 18:05:01 GMT'

central = timezone('US/Central')
published_time = datetime.strptime(time_stamp, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
published_cst = published_time.astimezone(central)
actual_time_published = published_cst.strftime('%a, %b %d %Y at %I:%M:%S %p %Z')




print(time_stamp)
print(published_time)
print(published_cst)
print(actual_time_published)
```

Expecting acutal_time_published to be CST because published_cst has GMT-6 hours (third result), but here is the actual result for each print command.

```
Mon, 17 Dec 2018 18:05:01 GMT
2018-12-17 18:05:01
2018-12-17 18:05:01-06:00
Mon, Dec 17 2018 at 06:05:01 PM CST
```

Pulling my hair out!

EDIT: Yes, I had "entry.published" where I meant to put "time_stamp" for the purposes of this question. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: I can't reproduce this — your code as given wasn't runnable, so please double check. It gives `Mon, Dec 17 2018 at 12:05:01 PM CST` as the last line for me.

Comment: Thank you yes, I had "entry.published" where I meant to put "time_stamp" for the purposes of this question. Apologies.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out! Even though the original time stamp was returning a timezone (GMT), it did not have a tzinfo value (timezone value) assigned to it. It was still a "naive" datetime, even though the string contained a timezone recognized by strptime. So, I just assigned a tzinfo value of UTC to the original time and it seemed to fix it.

```
time_stamp = 'Mon, 17 Dec 2018 18:05:01 GMT'
utc = timezone('UTC')
central = timezone('US/Central')
published_time = datetime.strptime(time_stamp, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
published_gmt = published_time.replace(tzinfo=utc)
published_cst = published_gmt.astimezone(central)
actual_time_published = published_cst.strftime('%a, %b %d %Y at %I:%M:%S %p %Z')
```

So...

```
print(time_stamp)
print(published_time)
print(published_cst)
print(actual_time_published)
```

Yeilds this output:

```
Mon, 17 Dec 2018 18:05:01 GMT
2018-12-17 18:05:01
2018-12-17 18:05:01+00:00
2018-12-17 12:05:01-06:00
Mon, Dec 17 2018 at 12:05:01 PM CST
```

Comment: Aha, I was attempting to reproduce this on a machine in UTC.